# Display driver ghosting pixels on linux but not on Windows

Tags: video, display

I recently bought an lcd panel for a raspberry pi display device I'm making. The pi outputs hdmi video to the display driver for the panel. The pi is outputting `1366x768 @ 60hz`.

The problem is about 800 pixels from the left it has this weird orange/blue ghosting effect, and then the screen completely repeats for the last 50-100 pixels or so. This also happens when I try to use it as a second monitor on my ubuntu laptop. When I use it as a second monitor on windows, this problem does not occur, even though it says windows is also outputting `1366x768 @ 60hz`. Here is a picture:

[image: Screen Issue]

The section with the magenta box around it is where it ghosts orange and blue. The section with the cyan box is where it completely repeats the ending of the screen image (notice the two X's in the upper right corner of the image viewer window). Has anyone ever seen something like this before? What is windows sending to the display driver that the Linux OSs aren't?